# How to check whether a windows process was launched by user or another process?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, operating-system, pid

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136366/is-it-possible-to-find-out-whether-a-process-was-started-by-a-user-or-by-another) one, but I am hoping for clarification. I'm asking about Windows in particular. It is noted in the comments there that we can check the parent process. That's fine, but I'm wondering how robust that is in practice.

- When a user launches a program, can you count on the parent process to be always the same (and what would that be)?
- Conversely, if a program is launched by another program, can it somehow be made to appear that a user launched it?

Comment: absolute unclear about what you asking. *if a program is launched by another program* - this is not if but always. again - what is mean *user launches a program* ? and be exactly - windows not save information about parent process. windows store information about inherit from process. this is usual the same but not always. and main - what is real problem ?

Comment: I'm talking about the distinction between starting program A manually, versus starting program B which at some point launches program A in the background. I don't know how well-defined this distinction is, and that's the reason for my question.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make that distinction.  Maybe if you told us what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, someone could suggest something else.

Comment: @DanKorn I am wondering whether a program can behave differently depending on how it is launched.

Comment: @SauceCode - again too broad question. program can check command line, inherited from process, token, etc. and based on this behave differently. it can check some named object too. so - in what question ?

Comment: There are different logon types, e.g. interactive, service, and batch. Maybe what you want is for the executable to also support running as a service or batch task?

Comment: A user "never" launches a process: The user always interacts with some other process and gets that process to launch the new app. Typically the user would be using explorer.exe (which is the process backing the start menu, desktop and taskbar) or cmd.exe (command line / batch script based launches).

Comment: Yes, a program can definitely behave differently depending on how it is launched, or by whom.  For instance, you can have a program run differently if it's launched interactively (by a logged-on user) versus as a system process or service.  But that's not your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable way to verify, whether a process was started in response to user interaction or not.

> When a user launches a program, can you count on the parent process to be always the same (and what would that be)?

No. There is an unbounded number of applications that users can interact with to launch a process (Windows File Explorer, Total Commander, Windows Command Prompt, ConEmu, Cygwin, and so on). In addition, the parent process could long be gone by the time you are checking.

> Conversely, if a program is launched by another program, can it somehow be made to appear that a user launched it?

There is no property inherent to a process launched by a user. The question whether you can establish a property that doesn't exists is rather philosophical.